# Group 2d array's row data by one column and sum another column within each group to produce a reduced 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, counting

I need group rows of data by a column and sum another column.

Input:

```
[
    ['quantity' => 5,  'dd' => '01-Nov-2012'],
    ['quantity' => 10, 'dd' => '01-Nov-2012'],
    ['quantity' => 3,  'dd' => '02-Nov-2012'],
    ['quantity' => 4,  'dd' => '03-Nov-2012'],
    ['quantity' => 15, 'dd' => '03-Nov-2012'],
];
```

Desired result:

```
[
    ['quantity' => 15, 'dd' => '01-Nov-2012'],
    ['quantity' => 3,  'dd' => '02-Nov-2012'],
    ['quantity' => 19, 'dd' => '03-Nov-2012'],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop trough the rows, and add up the quantities in a different array indexed by the `dd` values.

```
$in = array(array()); // your input
$out = array();
foreach ($in as $row) {
    if (!isset($out[$row['dd']])) {
        $out[$row['dd']] = array(
            'dd' => $row['dd'],
            'quantity' => 0,
        );
    }
    $out[$row['dd']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
}
$out = array_values($out); // make the out array numerically indexed
var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Orrrrr... Since the days are unique:

```
  <?php

  header('Content-type: text/plain');

  $inputArray  = array(
    array('qty' => 5,  'dd'  => '01-Nov-2012'),
    array('qty' => 10, 'dd'  => '01-Nov-2012'),
    array('qty' => 3,  'dd'  => '02-Nov-2012'),
    array('qty' => 4,  'dd'  => '03-Nov-2012'),
    array('qty' => 15, 'dd'  => '03-Nov-2012'));

  $outputArray = array();

  foreach ( $inputArray as $record ) {
    if ( !key_exists($record['dd'], $outputArray) ) {
      $outputArray[$record['dd']] = 0;
    }
    $outputArray[$record['dd']] += $record['qty'];
  }

  print_r($outputArray);
```

would produce:

```
Array
(
    [01-Nov-2012] => 15
    [02-Nov-2012] => 3
    [03-Nov-2012] => 19
)
```

Comment: This advice belongs on: [Group array data on one column and sum data from another column to form a flat associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3286749/2943403) asked in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of viable techniques to group and sum your 2d array data.

1. `foreach()` with temporary keys: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FI2AC))

   ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($array as $row) {
       if (!isset($result[$row['dd']])) {
           $result[$row['dd']] = $row;
       } else {
           $result[$row['dd']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
       }
   }
   var_export(array_values($result));
   ```
2. `foreach()` with references instead of temporary result keys: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FsSnj))

   ```
   $result = [];
   foreach ($array as $row) {
       if (!isset($ref[$row['dd']])) {
           $ref[$row['dd']] = $row;
           $result[] = &$ref[$row['dd']];
       } else {
           $ref[$row['dd']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
       }
   }
   var_export($result);
   ```
3. `array_reduce()` with temporary keys: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OSi1E))

   ```
   var_export(
       array_values(
           array_reduce(
               $array,
               function($result, $row) {
                   if (!isset($result[$row['dd']])) {
                       $result[$row['dd']] = $row;
                   } else {
                       $result[$row['dd']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
                   }
                   return $result;
               }
           )
       )
    );
   ```
4. `array_reduce()` with references instead of temporary keys: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N0pAC))

   ```
   var_export(
       array_reduce(
           $array,
           function($result, $row) {
               static $ref = [];
               if (!isset($ref[$row['dd']])) {
                   $ref[$row['dd']] = $row;
                   $result[] = &$ref[$row['dd']];
               } else {
                   $ref[$row['dd']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
               }
               return $result;
           }
       )
   );
   ```

---

To execute more summing actions with other column values, duplicate the summing action found in the `else` branch of any of these snippets.

For example:

```
} else {
    $result[$row['dd']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
    $result[$row['dd']]['anotherColumn'] += $row['anotherColumn'];
    // ... and so on
}
```

---

To group by more than one column, create a "composite key" by concatentating multiple column values into a single, temporary string key.  Here are some demonstrations of the technique:

- [Group multidimensional array data based on two column values and sum values of one column in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65157947/2943403)
- [Group/Merge rows from two 2d arrays based on 3 identifying columns and fill missing column values with null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844352/2943403)
- [Group rows of data, sum number of occurrences in each group, and print data as formatted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73356699/2943403)
- [Group data in a multidimensional array based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372130/2943403)
- [Group rows of a multidimensional array and form comma-separated values within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73172252/2943403)
- [Group rows by two columns, filter grouped data to only keep the lowest value, and restructure associative rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74065614/2943403)
- [Group rows of data, maintain a subarray of ids within the group, and only present the lowest id in each group as the first level key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73149340/2943403)
- [Group multidimensional array data based on two column values and sum values of one column in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65157947/2943403)
- [how to create a pivot array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71807560/2943403)