How to perform math additions on values in an array where a condition is met in php
So I'm fetching some data from a Db using Php. See the below result.
<pre style="color:gray">Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [depart_id] => 1
            [total] => 1073.00
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [depart_id] => 1
            [total] => 2775.50
            [currency] => ZAR
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [depart_id] => 4
            [total] => 900.00
            [currency] => USD
        )

)
</pre>

As you can see the data is grouped by depart_id and currency. Now what I want is to add the 2 [total] where the depart_id is the same such that the result retain would be as below.
Note that I would want to implement a rate conversion logic from the ZAR to USD once the condition is met, then perform the addition. For now for the purpose of easy of understanding what I'm trying to achieve, required result is disregarding that conversion logic.
<pre style="color:gray">Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [depart_id] => 1
            [total] => 3848.50
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [depart_id] => 4
            [total] => 900.00
            [currency] => USD
        )

)
</pre>

Thanks guys.

change the query with GROUP BY depart_id and sum( total) as total

@nbk if i do that won't be able to apply exchange rate conversion logic

my ocmment would be fatser, but you can always loop over all array see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284036/group-2d-arrays-row-data-by-one-column-and-sum-another-column-within-each-group

those are good, thanks, because they would allow me to implement some logic before i get the final 2d array result. Many thanks
