# Remove wholly duplicate rows from a 2d array and count number of occurrences of each unique row

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, grouping, counting

I need filter out duplicate rows in my 2d array and in the retained unique rows append an element that contains the count of how many times the unique row existed in the original array.

I wanted to use `array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR)`, but removing duplicates is not enough -- I actually need to get store the count of the duplicated rows per with the unique rows.

I have tried `array_search()` and loops, but none of my attempts yield the correct results.  My project data has upwards of 500,000 entries, but here's a basic example:

Input:

```
[
    ['manufacturer' => 'KInd', 'brand' => 'ABC', 'used' => 'true'],
    ['manufacturer' => 'KInd', 'brand' => 'ABC', 'used' => 'true'],
    ['manufacturer' => 'KInd', 'brand' => 'ABC', 'used' => 'false'],
]
```

Output:

```
[
    ['manufacturer' => 'KInd', 'brand' => 'ABC', 'used' => 'true', 'count' => 2],
    ['manufacturer' => 'KInd', 'brand' => 'ABC', 'used' => 'false', 'count' => 1],
]
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: You must have a way to identify an object. So you can loop the original array, checking each element (object), and counting how many copies are found of each unique object.

Comment: @KenLee added sample array to the question

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP tried that, but since the size of the array, looping is very costly. Could you be more specific about the counting, is it going to be a loop inside a loop?

Comment: array_count_values($yourArray) will return an array with your object and number of occurrences

Comment: @KhaledHassan array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!
It's an object array, so can't use the array_count_values(), already tried that. Thanks

Comment: You comment above: "but since the size of the array, looping is very costly". Sorry, but what do you think what functions like `array_unique()` or `array_search()` do if not looping/iterating over the array? There is no way around that.

Comment: @arkascha yeah, you're correct. array_search also takes a good amount of time. That's why searching for an alternate solution, if there's no way have to do the loop

Comment: If it's from a database you might do a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`: `SELECT  a,b,c,count(a) FROM table GROUB BY a,b,c`

Comment: @Michel it's not from the db, it's from a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any elaborate serialization or encoding to create composite keys for grouping.  Just implode each row's values (assuming they all contain the same columns in the same order) to create an identifying key for the result array.

On the first encounter, store the row's data in the group and set the group's count to 1; on any subsequent encounter, increment the group's counter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mB8AJ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $compositeKey = implode('_', $row);
    if (!isset($result[$compositeKey])) {
        $result[$compositeKey] = $row + ['count' => 1];
    } else {
        ++$result[$compositeKey]['count'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'manufacturer' => 'KInd',
    'brand' => 'ABC',
    'used' => 'true',
    'count' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'manufacturer' => 'KInd',
    'brand' => 'ABC',
    'used' => 'false',
    'count' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Other posts that leverage multiple identifying column values for grouping:

- [Group/Merge rows from two 2d arrays based on 3 identifying columns and fill missing column values with null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844352/2943403)
- [Group rows of data, sum number of occurrences in each group, and print data as formatted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73356699/2943403)
- [Group data in a multidimensional array based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372130/2943403)
- [Group rows of a multidimensional array and form comma-separated values within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73172252/2943403)
- [Group rows by two columns, filter grouped data to only keep the lowest value, and restructure associative rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74065614/2943403)
- [Group rows of data, maintain a subarray of ids within the group, and only present the lowest id in each group as the first level key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73149340/2943403)
- [Group multidimensional array data based on two column values and sum values of one column in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65157947/2943403)
- [how to create a pivot array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71807560/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should help

```
function getUniqWithCounts(array $data): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $hash = md5(serialize($item));

        if (isset($result[$hash])) {
            $result[$hash]['count']++;
            continue;
        }
        $item['count'] = 1;
        $result[$hash] = $item;
    }

    return array_values($result);
}
```